# xcode: segmented control appears on sim, not on device

Tags: xcode, device, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an iPad app with several segmented controls, including one view with two controls.

On that view, everything shows in the sim, both normal and retina. However, in the device, only one shows.

Below is the code that does not show on the device.. I have checked and all the images that make up the control are copied in the bundle resources. I've tried removing, cleaning, etc. No joy. I must be missing something (hopefully simple)..

```
 UISegmentedControl *controls = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
 [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],                 
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"], 
 nil]];

 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(35, 70, 700, 35);
 controls.frame = frame;

 }

[controls addTarget:self action:@selector(drawSegmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

controls.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
controls.momentary = YES;
controls.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:controls];

}
```

For reference, this code in the same view does work:

For reference, this control code does work:

```
-(void) buildColorBar {
//NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

 UISegmentedControl *colorControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"White.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple.png"],                         
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Black.png"],

                                         nil]];

NSLog(@"Portrait");
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(35, 950, 700, 35);
colorControl.frame = frame;

     // When the user chooses a color, the method changeBrushColor: is called.
     [colorControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeBrushColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

     colorControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

     // Make sure the color of the color complements the black background
     colorControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];

     // Add the control to the window
     [self.view addSubview:colorControl];


}
```

Is there a rule against using two segmented controls in one view?

Comment: Obvious questions... have you put in an NSLog and made sure that code is being run? How about just making a UIView with some random background color to see if it's a problem creating the control or if it's more of a basic layout/adding subview problem?

Comment: Yep, the code is logged and is running. I can see that the buttons work too (on the sim). Weird ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that one image in the segmented control - while it looked like it was in the bundle  - it wasn't. PITA, but at least, it works..